# Можно ли сделать refresh google banner без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Мне нужно на сайте обновлять google banner каждых например 3-5 минут. Без рефреша всей страницы и так, чтобы гугл не забанил. Возможно ли такое? Пример, кода банера.

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:600px"
     data-ad-client="xxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxx"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, можно, пример [отсюда](http://www.barattalo.it/coding/refresh-a-google-adsense-banner-with-javascript/):

Создаете файл refresh-banner-iframe.php где будет ваш скрипт для AdSense:

```
<script src="http://www.example.com/getAdsenseScript.php?id=19"></script>
```

Добавляете iframe с сылкой на этот файл:

```
<iframe src="refresh-banner-iframe.php" width="728" height="90"></iframe>
```

Для обновления баннера вызываете через javascript:

```
$url = $('iframe').attr("src");
$('iframe').attr("src","about:blank");
$('iframe').attr("src",$url);
```

Насчет забанит Google вас или нет не знаю.

Answer (score 13):

**Автоматическое обновление объявлений**

> Издателям запрещено обновлять страницу или ее элемент без
>   соответствующего запроса пользователя. Подразумевается, кроме прочего,
>   показ объявлений на страницах или в других местах размещения с
>   автоматической переадресацией или автоматическим обновлением.
>   Издателям также нельзя устанавливать время ожидания перед показом
>   контента, например видео, игр или файлов для скачивания, и
>   транслировать в это время рекламу (т. н. видеореклама в начале
>   ролика).

**Объявления на страницах без контента**

> Издателям запрещено размещать объявления на вспомогательных страницах
>   (входа, выхода, сообщения об ошибке, благодарности и т. п.). Это
>   разделы сайта, которые посетители видят, собираясь покинуть сайт или
>   совершив определенные действия, например покупку или скачивание.
>
> На таких страницах объявления оказываются в центре внимания, и
>   посетитель может ошибочно принять их за часть контента, поэтому не
>   следует размещать на них рекламу.

Ссылка на источник: [Внедрение рекламного кода. Правила размещения объявлений](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1346295?hl=ru&ref_topic=1307438#Auto-refreshing_ads)

Перейти на страницу <kbd>Внедрение рекламного кода. Правила размещения объявлений</kbd> перейти в раздел <kbd>Обеспечение надлежащего размещения объявлений</kbd>, содержащий достаточно понятные пункты <kbd>Автоматическое обновление объявлений</kbd> и <kbd>Объявления на страницах без контента</kbd>

На [форуме](https://productforums.google.com/forum) достаточное количество подобных вопросов и ответов, баннеры такого рода - нарушают правила размещения рекламных баннеров. Примеры тем на форуме с подобным вопросом: [Можно ли обновлять рекламный баннер адсенс через некоторое время](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense-ru/dHfIVIXborE;context-place=topicsearchin/adsense-ru/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5$20) или: [Обновления рекламы через AJAX](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense-ru/r1ddKQPQL_I;context-place=topicsearchin/adsense-ru/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5$20) или [Смена (загрузка) объявлений через AJAX (по таймауту или вместе с другим блоком страницы)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/adsense-ru/birCh74dZ5U)

Даже если Ваш код, который будет делать автоматическое обновление заработает, то через определенное время, рано или поздно, Ваши баннеры будут заблокированы и потом придется мучительно все восстанавливать, так как Вы будете [забанены](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/adsense-ru/4j0VBp0lD5A/2rdiR_HEBwAJ).

Мой ответ - сделать можно (через `iframe`, `Ajax` или через `JS`), но вы будете рано или поздно забанены, поэтому не стоит нарушать правила размещения объявлений.

Comment: На самом деле гугл сам не шибко следит за своими правилами. Например "Издателям запрещено обновлять страницу" - 2 года несколько топ сайтов(к которым у меня имеется сорц-доступ) нарушает: реклама жива. Также нарушали "запрет на баннеры под меню" - тоже прокатывало. Так что `но вы будете все равно забанены` - весьма условно..

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, да, многие нарушали, но рано или поздно все вычисляется. Там ведь не глупые люди и они явно не заинтересованы платить за то, что кто-то более *продуманный*. Возможно условно, но тут лишь дело времени, правила ведь будут нарушены.

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, Денис, я тебя умоляю. Тут народ сделал ботов, которые всю рекламу скликивают - вот это нарушение. А обновление с интервалом 30-50 минут - на честном поле, морально даже не выглядит нарушением.

Answer (score 2):

обычный js - создаем элемент баннера в виде div

и баннер вносим в страницу

для "чистоты" вида..

и по функции факта загрузки страницы запускаем скрипт:

```
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/recl.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="boot();">
    <div id="rek"'>src="http://www.example.com/getAdsenseScript.php?id=19</div>
    </body>

    сам скрипт... вида
    <script>
    var banner='src="http://www.example.com/getAdsenseScript.php?id=19"'
    function task(fn) {
    return fn;
    };
    function bann(ban,cb) {
    setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById('rekl').innerHTML=ban; return task(bann);},1000);
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если для удобства манипуляций с DOM прикрутить jquery, то получится следующий код:

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
     return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
function reload_js(src) {
     $('script[src="' + src + '"]').remove();
     $('<script>').attr('src', src).appendTo('head');
}
setInterval(function(){
     //Тут подставляем путь до гугло-скрипта         
     reload_js('//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js');
}, getRandom(180000, 300000));
```

По сути, перезапускает гугло-скрипт через рандомный промежуток от 3 до 5 минут для каждой сессии. Так как грузится он асинхронно, врятли заметит собственный перезапуск, т.к. элементы скорее всего будут загружены раньше.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать перезагрузку рекламного блока используя официальную инструкцию от Google Double Click for Publishers , это по сути бесплатная "рекламная крутилка" куда можно вживлять любые коды, таргетировать и т.п. https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2694377?hl=ru

Что касается Adsense - его раз в определенный интервал перезагружать нельзя, но можно перезагружать со сменой элементов на странице, например в слайдерах как это сделано здесь, вполне официально и без риска бана http://www.elle.com/beauty/makeup-skin-care/tips/g8447/elle-editors-favorite-face-wash/?slide=3

Comment: Дополните вопрос материалам из ссылок, по возможности с примерами.